# Programs output CPU and RAM usage in plots (if possible)

Tags: ram, cpu

I want to know how much of RAM my pipeline consumed for each step. However, the program need hour to completed and I cannot stay in my computer for tracking the usage on thousands of files. I found no programs that can output the usage of RAM and CPU in plots. Does anyone know such a program on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would recommend [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). I'm inclined to say the possibilities are almost endless.

However, Grafana is "only" a viewer, so you also need a data collecting backend - for this you can use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

Finally you need the [Prometheus Node Exporter](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/prometheus-node-exporter) installed on each machine where you want to gather metrics.

I've installed this set of tools using Docker containers - I find that this is the easiest way. However, it requires a little research on your side to set up things like you want it.

Here are the links to the official Docker images I can recommend:

[Grafana - Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana)

[Prometheus - Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus)

And finally, you need to install the Node exporter on the machines where you want to gather data. Make sure the "Universe" repositories are enabled in your `/etc/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe
```

Then run the installation on each machine:

```
sudo apt install prometheus-node-exporter
```

Prometheus has very good [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/) about how to configure, and there is an example configuration file [on Github here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.27/config/testdata/conf.good.yml).

In your prometheus config, you need a job that targets the machines where Node Exporter is running. In the below example, I have two machines (10.10.2.2 and 10.10.2.4) with Node Exporter running on port 9100.

```
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['10.10.2.2:9100', '10.10.2.4:9100']
```

In Grafana, you then need a dashboard to show the statistics for Node Exporter. Here I can recommend the [Node Exporter Full dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860) to begin with.

Everything can be customized, but at least now you can start to see the historic data on your machines.

Comment: Thanks, I will try